# C sendmsg() no buffer space available

Tags: c

I'm not an expert in C programming, but I'm trying to write a fairly simple program using sendmsg() and recvmsg() to send a message between a client and a server (both are on the same machine, so basically I'm sending a message to localhost).

After initialising the required structures (as in the iovec and the msghdr) and succesfully connecting the client to the server, my sendmsg() call fails with "no buffer space avaliable" errno.

This is what linux man reports about this type of error:

> The  output queue for a network interface was full.  This generally indicates that the interface has stopped sending,  but  maybe  caused  by  transient  congestion.  (Normally, this does not occur in Linux.  Packets are just silently dropped when a device queue overflows.)

I looked around on the Internet and as a result I found out that sendmsg() is not widely used, and nobody could relate with this type of error. The only useful advice I found was to check a possible excess of open sockets, but again I always close EVERY socket I create.

So I'm stuck, basically because being quite the noob I don't know exactly where to look to fix this kind of problem.

If anybody knows how to proceed, it would be great.
(And please don't tell me not to use sendmsg(), because the whole purpose of my work is to understand this syscall, and not send a message to myself)

Here's the code I've written so far on pastebin: [client](http://pastebin.com/RESELfvv) and [server](http://pastebin.com/wfGUcHvP)

--SOLVED--

Thank you very much. I've been able to solve the problem and I fixed other mistakes I made, so here's the functioning code for sendmsg() and recvmsg() working message-passing: [Client](http://pastebin.com/nze9gznA) and [Server](http://pastebin.com/vcmspYCY)

Comment: or unix domain (or socketpair)?

Comment: You mean the `ENOBUFS` error, right? Well, that's indeed strange. Can you provide a minimal test-case where it happens so somebody else can try reproducing it?

Comment: I use a connection-oriented AF_INET socket (type SOCK_STREAM), so TCP.

Comment: Here's what I've done so far:
client --> [link](http://pastebin.com/RESELfvv) 
server --> [link](http://pastebin.com/wfGUcHvP)
It's really basic code, but as I said I'm quite the noob.

Comment: @xHawk Please note how quickly you got actual answers, once you showed your code. Feel free to draw conclusions regarding the relative worth of a) talk describing code, and b) actual code. Especially when it's *known* that the code has one or more errors ...

Comment: Sorry, but it's also the first time I ask a question online. I will remember that the next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, iovlen should be 1. But also, you want to zero out mh before initializing some of its fields since you're probably sending in garbage in the uninitialized fields and the syscall gets confused. Also, it doesn't really make sense to set msg_name and msg_namelen since you're connected and can't change your mind about where to send the data anyway.

This is what works for me in your client code:

```
/* The message header contains parameters for sendmsg.    */
memset(&mh, 0, sizeof(mh));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
mh.msg_iov = iov;
mh.msg_iovlen = 1;

printf("mh structure initialized \n");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, both for the code and the explanation, this was really helpful.

Comment: Please do not `memset` structs, but rather explicitly initialize members. Using `memset` makes an assumption abour the binary representation of values which may not always hold true.

Comment: @SimonRichter while that is theoretically correct, in practice I'd say it doesn't matter anymore. I don't think any system where sendmsg works will have a non-zero bit representations of null pointers or floating point numbers. The battle for alternative bit representations has been lost long ago when calloc was added to the C standard, then made useless by its formal definition that conflicts with its intended usage and then attempted to be fixed with a footnote. If you read C11 like a devils advocate you'll find that even two-complement assumptions have snuck in.

Answer (score 3):

The `msg_iovlen` field contains the number of elements in the *iov* array, not its size in bytes.

The system interpreted the following uninitialized memory as *iov* elements, ended up with a packet that is larger than the socket buffer space available, and thus refused to send the data.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so in your code I found this:

```
mh.msg_iovlen = sizeof(iov);
```

Which sets the `msg_iovlen` member to the size of `struct iovec`. But the documentation says this about this field:

> size_t        msg_iovlen;     /* # elements in msg_iov */

So your code is wrong, it tells `sendmsg()` that it's going to send way more elements than you actually initialize.